# setInterval in greasemonkey for chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, greasemonkey, setinterval

In greasemonkey for chrome I'm using a function addJQuery(callback) that load jQuery and execute the callback function. So I call addJQuery(main). Inside main() i have a function colorizeMe() that i must call every 5 seconds.

```
function main() {
        //change something using jQuery
        $("#myid").css("width", "10%");

    function colorizeMe(){
        //colorize something using jQuery
                $("#myid").css("color", "red");
    }
    setInterval("colorizeMe()", 5000);
}
addJQuery(main);
```

This doesn't work and i have the error
Uncaught ReferenceError: colorizeMe is not defined

where and how i have to define the function colorizeMe() ? If i put colorizeMe() out of main i can use jQuery inside...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
setInterval(colorizeMe, 5000);
```

Then the main of your user script should be:

```
function main() {
    //change something using jQuery
    $("#myid").css("width", "10%");

    function colorizeMe(){
        //colorize something using jQuery
        $("#myid").css("color", "red");
    }
    setInterval(colorizeMe, 5000);
}
```

Comment: doesn't work: Uncaught ReferenceError: colorizeMe is not defined

Comment: Have you uninstalled the old and reinstalled the updated user script? I have no problems with this one.